# ServerSelectionTimeoutError while connecting to Mongodb using Pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have installed Mongodb on VPS running Ubuntu 22.04 with IP address 31.xxx.xx.xxx (I have changed to this in the error too)

When I try to connect to this using Pymongo in Python, I get:

```
ServerSelectionTimeoutError: 31.xxx.xx.xxx: timed out
  (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms, connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms),
  Timeout: 30s,
  Topology Description:
    <TopologyDescription id: 654b35f4fa214d7836c927,
     topology_type: Unknown,
     servers: [
      <ServerDescription ('31.xxx.xx.xxx', 27017) server_type: Unknown,
       rtt: None,
       error=NetworkTimeout('31.xxx.xx.xxx:27017: timed out
         (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms,
          connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms
         )'
        )
      >
     ]
    >
```

I added a user, gave the user "root" role under "admin" db, changed the conf file and enabled authorization, but still nothing seems to work. This is the code that I am using:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

mongo_uri = "mongodb://admin:123@31.xxx.xx.xxx"
client = MongoClient(mongo_uri)
db = client['admin']
print(db.list_collection_names())
client.close()
```

[image: The Mongodb service is active and running perfectly fine on my VPS]

Comment: Please post the error as a text, not a screenshot.

Comment: I have already posted it :
ServerSelectionTimeoutError: 31.xxx.xx.xxx: timed out (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms, connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms), Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 654b35f4fa214d7836c927, topology_type: Unknown, servers: [<ServerDescription ('31.xxx.xx.xxx', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=NetworkTimeout('31.xxx.xx.xxx:27017: timed out (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms, connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms)')>]>

Comment: `mongod.log` should show the IP Address and port the server is listening on.  Is it what you expect?  If so, is there a firewall that might prevent reaching it?

Comment: FINALLY!! Yes, the firewall was preventing it! 
Fixed it by allowing. Thank you so much!